# No mention of eMMC random performance in datasheets

Tags: datasheet, performance, emmc

Any particular reason why none of the eMMC manufacturers mention random read or random write performance in datasheets ? Only performance mentioned in datasheets is for sequential workloads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None? I opened two random eMMC datasheets and they both do mention it.

[First](https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/global.semi/file/resource/2017/11/Samsung_eMMC_2013-0.pdf) : Random read/write 4866/1542 IOPS

[Second](https://www.issi.com/WW/pdf/IS21_22ES08G.pdf) : Random read/write e.g. 2500/200 IOPS

Comment: Sorry, was looking mainly at Kingston. And checked a couple of Sandisk and Longsys

Comment: And why are random workload performance in IOPS and sequential performance in MB/s

Comment: @AnnG IOPS are how many operations per second the storage can do.  MB/s per second is how many bytes per second those transfers copy.  For random performance, IOPS are more useful to know since they are independent of transfer size.

Comment: Thanks @user1850479